# Working Sound/Vibrate/LED of notification until i cancel it?

Tags: android

Noti code :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.work_alarm_icon)
                                .setContentTitle("Alarm")
                                .setContentText(w.toString())
                                .setContentIntent(pintent)  
                                .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.google.app.workalarm/" + R.raw.alarm))
                                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("..."));    
        noti.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
        noti.setLights(Color.WHITE, 1000, 500);
        noti.setVibrate(new long[]{0,500,250,500});
```

I want to listen sound/vibrate and led until i cancel it. (when i click button Cancel in new activity).
Help me ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with notification's features. If you need, you shall open your activity and do your sound/vibrate there